# Issue with the class path in netbeans project

Tags: java, opencv, netbeans

I am doing an image processing application. For that i am using OpenCV-300.jar file. But when i run the program it gives the UnSatisfiedLinkError. When I search for the win32-x86 folder which contain dll file required for the jar, It was not available inside build folder within the project. How can I solve this? I went through all the tutorials related to solving UnSatisfiedLinkError for the whole day. But non of them worked for me. Please help me. Thank you in advance

Comment: you can add resources to your projects with a right click on resource and add jar/folder or library file to your project in netbeans hope it will help when you use netbeans

Comment: I did that. But it gave the same error

Comment: can you provide your code snippet where you load jar file

Comment: I added jar file just by right clicking the libraries and add jar/folder option. I didn't deal with any coding stuff.